# Como resolver System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

A minha aplicação (usando Xamarin Forms) estava funcionando tudo ok, mais do nada quando vou clicar no botão de login ela está sendo interrompida disparando o seguinte erro:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Como resolver isso?

Para deixar claro, não há nenhum erro no script, está tudo ok, até porque eu estava rodando tudo ok e do nada deu isso.
Resalvo que na lista de erros não há nada sendo exibido e já limpei a solução e reiniciei o visual studio mais não resolveu!

Meu xaml do loginPage:

```
<ContentPage Title="Login">
    <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="20"
                 VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Image 
        VerticalOptions="Center"
         HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Source="logo.png"/>

        <Entry x:Name="emailEntry" Placeholder="Usuário"
               Text="{Binding Usuario}"/>
        <Entry x:Name="senhaEntry" Placeholder="Senha"
               Text="{Binding Senha}"
               IsPassword="true"/>

        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="waitActivityIndicator"
                               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        </ActivityIndicator>
        <Button x:Name="loginButton"
                Text="Login" TextColor="White"
                BackgroundColor="#800000"
                Clicked="BtnLogin_Clicked"/>

    </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

E aqui o CodeBehind:

```
public LoginPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);    
}

protected async void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.Current.MainPage = new MainPageRoot();
}
```

Aqui o XAML da MainPagel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="EbsHelpDesk.Views.MainPage"
             Title="Home">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Padding="20">
            <Label Text="Atendimentos em Aberto"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   FontSize="25"/>
                <Grid  ColumnSpacing="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions/>
                    <Label Text="#" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="coluna0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  SeparatorColor="White"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"/>
                    <Label Text="Colaborador" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="coluna1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  SeparatorColor="White"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"/>
                    <Label Text="Cliente" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    <ListView x:Name="coluna2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"  SeparatorColor="White"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"/>
                    <Label Text="Duração" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="coluna3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"  SeparatorColor="White"
                SeparatorVisibility="Default"/>
                </Grid>

                <Label Text="Minhas Tarefas"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   FontSize="25"/>
                <Label Text="Sistema:"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                   FontSize="12"/>
                <Picker x:Name="pckSistema" Title="Selecione o sistema:">
                    <Picker.Items>
                        <x:String>CORREÇÃO DE ERRO</x:String>
                        <x:String>MELHORIA DE SISTEMA</x:String>
                        <x:String>NOVA FUNCIONALIDADE</x:String>
                        <x:String>NOVO RELATÓRIO/ETIQUETA</x:String>
                        <x:String>OBRIGAÇÕES FISCAIS</x:String>
                        <x:String>MIGRAÇÃO DE SISTEMA</x:String>
                    </Picker.Items>
                </Picker>
                <Button Text="Criar Chamado"
                    TextColor="White"
                    BackgroundColor="#008000"
                    Image="tarefa24.png"
                    />
        </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: @LINQ não há base nenhuma? Se não é um erro no script, o que eu deveria colocar na pergunta então???

Comment: @WPfan Informações relevantes (???) Onde esta rodando, qual a versão do Xamarin, se a aplicação chega iniciar, etc.

Comment: @LINQ mais será possivel que ninguém lê a tag indicando ao que se refere não, pois lembro muito bem de ter informado xamarin-forms.... e sim, a aplicação inicia, pois como eu avisei o erro só dispara quando clicamos no botão LOGIN!

Comment: Você não está tentando interagir com algum elemento ou objeto que ainda não foi carregado? Sempre inclua o código relevante ao momento do erro...  nós não estamos vendo a sua aplicação e não tem como adivinhar o que está acontecendo sem ter o que interpretar...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo qual seria o código para informar? Pois a aplicação não mostra nada na lista de erros, apenas interrompi quando está sendo executada, disparando esse erro.... e outra, ela estava rodando normal, sem eu mexer em nada, apenas fechando e abrindo de novo dai começou dar isso!! Isso ta parecendo Delphi, pois ele que é bugado dessa forma!

Comment: @WPfan, se o erro é ao clicar no botão de login... comece incluindo o código do evento de click desse botão...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo vou editar incluindo, obrigado, isso sim é comentário relevante!

Comment: @WPFan não seria `Application.Current` ao invés de `App.Current`? Você também pode tentar adicionar um delay na thread só para testar.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo essa sintaxe não faz diferença, mas eu alterei mesmo assim pra desencargo de confiança e continua da mesma forma! Cara o que pode está causando isso, minha nossa... me atrasou completamente aqui!

Comment: Sem querer extender a discussão, acho que precisamos deixar algumas coisas claras: A comunidade StackOverflow (e seus usuários) tem ferramentas como sinalização, votos negativos e comentários para tornar o seu conteúdo relevante. O uso desses recursos não dá o direito a quem quer que seja de desrespeitar a comunidade. Se uma crítica for **improcedente** a própria comunidade irá descreditá-la com o passar do tempo. **Sinalizações e downvotes também é ajuda**, mas nesse caso ajuda a comunidade, e não um único indivíduo. Enfim, veja qual o comportamento esperado dos nossos membros [help/behavior]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então, descobri que o erro estava no `XAML` do mainpage, bastando apenas remover a tag   `<Grid.RowDefinitions/>`, dai voltou a funcionar normalmente.